# Number of implications needed

Tags: graph-theory

I need some math directions since I'm lost.

Problem:
I have $2$ values $n$  ($1 \le n \le 20000$) and $m$ ($0 \le m \le 50000$).
$n$ is the number of statements and $m$ is the number of implications that have already been proved.

I also have $m$ pair of values $s_1$ and $s_2$ ($1 \le s_1$,  $s_2 \le n$ and $s_1 \ne s_2$).
These pairs indicate that it has been proved that statement $s_1$ implies statement $s_2$.

I need to find the minimum number of additional implications that need to be proved in order to prove that all statements are equivalent.

I have the answer of 2 cases:

1. $n=4$
   $m=0$
   answer: $4$
2. $n=3$
   $m=2$
   pairs:
   $1,2$
   $1,3$
   answer: $2$

I don't understand why the answer is 4 and 2 respectively.

So my question is if somebody could point me in a direction on what I need to learn to solve this?
I've never read discrete math but that it has a implications part, is this it?

if so how should I interpret the data to make some neat implications equations e.g. $s_1 \to s_2$
and then make a implications table to calculate it?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your question.

Comment: what is the source of this problem?

Comment: @miracle173 actually its a programing assignment but I need to understand the math before I can implement a solution

Comment: so it is not about logic, it is about graphs, in particular about directed graphs. Are you familiar with the concept of graphs?

Comment: No, but I will check it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case, a graph with four vertices $\{a, b, c, d\}$ but no edges, you need to add at least four edges to make the cycle of statements
$$ a \implies b \implies c \implies d \implies a$$
and by a little experimenting, you can see that joining these vertices up into a loop like this is the most efficient way to solve it.

In the second case, you start with three vertices $\{a, b, c\}$ and the two edges $a \implies b$ and $a \implies c$. Firstly, you need to be able to start with $b$ or $c$ and get back to $a$, so you could add the two edges $\{b \implies a, c \implies a\}$, which would then give every implication. Otherwise, you could do something like add the edges $\{b \implies c, c \implies a\}$ which would also do the trick. Either way, adding two edges is the most efficient way to have every implication.

In general, you will be looking for a way to add the least number of edges to make the graph [strongly connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component). There are nice algorithms to reduce a graph to its strongly connected components, which leave you with the same problem to solve on a [directed acyclic graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph). So perhaps think of how to solve this problem first for a directed acyclic graph, then for a general graph.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how to solve the problem, but here some ideas how to reduce it to a bipartite graph. I will demonstrate this with some pictures. We start with a directed graph. The black circle is the end of an edge, usually drawn as an arrowhead. So in the following we have an edge from vertex $a$ to vertex $b$. [image]

First we replace a circle by a new vertex. We draw this new vertex as a square and name it by an uppercase letter.

[image]

This step is repeated until there are no more circles.

[image]

We are only interested in the sources (no incoming edges)  and the sinks (no outgoing edges).

[image]

If one has $u$ sources and $w$ sinks one has to add at least $\max\{u,w\}$ directed and at most about $u+w$ edges.

Here we have a solution after adding 4 edges (the minimal possible number):

[image]

But I don't know how  to find the minimal number  of edges to add systematically.